# Avoid in tests too much mock with static variable in source code

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I try to run several tests in once (using GoogleTest) on source code I wrote containing `static const` variable initialized through network (which is "mocked" to imitate real behavior).

Example `static const std::string myStr{getNameFromNetwork()};`

The fact is in the first test the mock on `getNameFromNetwork()` is OK, but from the second to the last test, the mock is too much because the variable is static AND already initialized.

Do you have any proposal to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, self-contained example that will reproduce the issue?

Comment: @TimRandall In this case code isn't really necessary it's more of a design question

Answer (score 1):

Shortly put: get rid of ALL your global data, since as you have found out global data makes testing difficult. The solution you are looking for is called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Summary :  Put all your previous data in an object with a standardized interface and inject that into the code that needs the data.
And read your data through that interface.

Example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// remove ALL you globals
// static const std::string myStr{ getNameFromNetwork() }; <== remove ALL globals

// define an interface (abstract baseclass) with getters to your data
struct global_data_itf
{
    virtual const std::string& get_name_from_network() const = 0;
    virtual ~global_data_itf() = default;

protected:
    global_data_itf() = default;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// provide an implementation with all your previous global settings

struct global_data :
    global_data_itf
{
    const std::string& get_name_from_network() const override
    {
        return myStr;
    }

    std::string myStr{ "network_name" };
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class your_class
{
public:

    your_class(const global_data_itf& data) :
        m_data{ data }
    {
    }

    void connect()
    {
        // instead of using static data use data from injected interface
        std::cout << m_data.get_name_from_network() << std::endl;
    }

private:
    const global_data_itf& m_data;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// test with default values

void test_case_1()
{
    global_data data;
    your_class object(data);

    object.connect();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// if you need to test with different configs/global data
// just instantiate a mock in you rest case

struct global_data_mock :
    global_data_itf
{
    const std::string& get_name_from_network() const override
    {
        return myStr;
    }

    std::string myStr{ "some other network name" };
};

void test_case_2()
{
    global_data_mock data;
    your_class object(data);
    object.connect();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    test_case_1();
    test_case_2();
    return 0;
}
```